# Não consegue encontrar a classe que está na mesma pasta quando tento criar um novo objeto

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

O erro dar  na linha 13 do `index.php` quando tento criar um novo objeto `"$c = new controleremoto"` diz que a classe não existe.

Sou novo na programação e já tentei de tudo, troquei de pasta, já pesquisei o erro no google e em vários resultados não consegui achar a reposta. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço de coração.

Aparece esse erro quando acesso o `index.php`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'controleremoto' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/edubr/index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/edubr/index.php on line 13
```

Se precisar de mais informações estou a disposição acho que coloquei tudo aqui. estou começando agora por favor tenha paciência.

controlador.php

```
<?php
interface controlador {
    public  function ligar();
    public  function desligar();
    public  function abrimenu();
    public  function fechamenu();
    public  function maisvolume();
    public  function menosvolume();
    public  function ligarmudo();
    public  function desligarmudo();
    public  function play();
    public  function pause();
}
?>
```

Controle Remoto.php

```
<?php
require_once 'controlado.php';

class controleremoto implements controlador  {
// atributos
private $volume;
private $ligado;
private $tocando;

// metodos especiais
function __construct() {
    $this->volume = 50;
    $this->ligado = false;
    $this->tocando = false;

}// gets
function getvolume() {
    return $this->volume;
}
function getligado() {
    return $this->ligado;
}
function gettocando() {
    return $this->tocando;
}// settes
function setvolume($volume) {
    $this->volume = $volume;
}
function setligado($ligado) {
    $this->ligado = $ligado;
}
function settocando($tocando) {
    $this->tocando = $tocando;

}// metodos abstrados
public function abrimenu() {
    echo "<br> Estar ligado?:" . ($this->getligado() ? "sim":"não");
    echo "<br está tocando?:" . ($this->gettocando()?"sim":"não");
    echo "<br> volume:" . $this->getvolume();
    for ($i=0; $i <= $this->getvolume(); $i+=10) {
        echo "i";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
public function fechamenu() {
    echo "<br>fechando muenu..";
}
public function desligar() {
    $this->setligado(false);
}
public function ligar() {
    $this->setligado(true);
}
public function maisvolume() {
    if ($this->getligado()) {
        $this->setvolume ($this->getvolume() + 5);
    }
}
public function menosvolume() {
    if ($this->getligado()) {
        $this->setligado($this->getvolume() - 5);
    }
}
public function ligarmudo() {
    if ($this->getligado() && $this->getvolume() >0) {
        $this->setvolume(0);
    }
}
public function desligarmudo() {
    if ($this->getligado() && $this->getvolume() ==0) {
        $this->setvolume(50);
    }
}
public function play() {
    if ($this->getligado() && ! ($this->gettocando())) {
        $this->settocando(true);
    }
}
public function pause() {
    if ($this->getligado() && $this->gettocando()) {
        $this->settocando(false);
    }
}


}

?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>curso em video</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> projeto controle remoto </h1>

<?php
require_once 'controlador.php';
$c = new controleremoto();
$c->ligar();
$c->abrimenu();


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está com alguns erros, o que é normal para quem está começando.

Primeiramente, o **require** é uma função, então precisa ser invocada de forma **require_once('arquivo.php');**

No arquivo *controleremoto.php*, logo na primeira linha, está faltando uma letra **'r'** no require.

Seu código:

```
require_once 'controlado.php';
```

Conforme você informou seu arquivo de interface chama **controlador.php**, logo:

```
require_once('controlador.php');
```

Em seu arquivo **index.php** você precisa chamar o arquivo onde está a classe, ao invés de chamar o arquivo com as interfaces, então na **linha 12** de seu index.php você troca a linha por:

```
require_once('controleremoto.php'); *//ou o nome do arquivo como você salvou, lembrando que não pode haver espaços*
```

Comment: Funcionouuuu! obrigadooo roberto ainda estou terminando o curso de poo e não tinha aprendido isso. sobre o r faltando estava  há mais de 06 horas tentando fazer funcionar o e nada. muito obrigado mesmo...

Comment: Que ótimo que funcionou! Bons estudos para você!